# Deployement strategy for 2 combined angular apps

Tags: angular, jenkins, cicd

My requirement was to have 2 Angular applications that works as a single app but should be deployable separately in 2 separate CI/CD pipelines. Also the 2 applications have 2 separate repositories on GIT and we use Jenkins for deployment. I am trying to combine 2 angular applications into a single one and was successfully able to do it using the following:

https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

I was able to successfully implement and it works as expected in my local. i.e localhost:4000. Basically I used ng generate application to created the application.

But I am not able to deploy it. We use Jenkins for deployment and its throwing an error. Something like src/app/app.module.ts:38:40 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'projects/xyz/.....

I have a separate CI/CD pipelines, one for the main application and the other for application1 ( which I have setup in projects folder ). It seems like while deploying, it is not able to find the sub-application because it is deployed in a different CI/CD or a different branch on git. Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

Comment: I know it's entire different setup, but did you try to check any monorepo like [nx](https://nrwl.io/)?

Comment: Maybe you should consider a monorepo for this setup? I think the issue is that you have multiple repos, but you also have a tight coupling between the apps. Another solution for this entire setup (one I would probably go for) - is Module Federation, which gives you a more strict separation between your apps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I did think of Module Federation but I am using Angular 10 and I have read that Module Federation should be used with Angular 12 because of webpack requirements. NX..... not sure. I though what I used was a simple solution so have not tried NX

Comment: I was thinking maybe there some change in Jenkins through which it can build multiple repositories